# Javascript async and await are not recognized on Tizen

Tags: webrtc, tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm trying to develop a simple WebRTC app for Samsung TV. I started by cut-n-pasting a simple WebRTC exampled into Tizen studio  and...I'm getting quite a bit of errors. In particular, Tizen studio does not seem to like "async" and "await"...why is that?

Comment: I am also interested in sending local tv channel to a remote location via WebRTC session. Where did you find an example of using WebRTC. I cannot find any references to this on Tizen TVs? I am c#.net programmer.

Comment: I didn't find anything. In fact, indent even understand how one can know what is supported and what not